# How to set a custom keymap and make sure, that it is not overwritten by system?

Tags: linux-mint, x11, key-mapping

I use custom keymap, that diffentiates between left and right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>:

```
remove control = Control_R
clear mod3
add Mod3 = Control_R
```

When I load it with `xmodmap myxmap`, it works only as long, as one of the events happens:

- Connect a HID (USB mouse, keyboard)
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Fx</kbd> to switch to text terminal

After that, I have to repeat the `xmodmap myxmap` command. I lived with it for over a year now, but it gets more and more annoying. Is there any way to tell the Linux Mint (Cinnamon edition) to keep my own version of assignment of `Control_R` key?

The issue concerns (but is not limited to) Linux Mint 14-16 Cinnamon 64 bit.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is probably to create a custom keymap.

A good step-by-step answer can be found here in this SuperUser Q&A titled: [How to change console keymap in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/290115/how-to-change-console-keymap-in-linux)

Comment: This is what I ended up doing and it works the best.

Comment: Do you know, what is the name of Mod3 in `keymaps`?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu and Linux Mint stores `xmodmap` settings in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc`.

When you edit the file, all changes are automatically preserved.

In my case I needed to insert a line with `modifier_map Mod3   { Control_R };`, and remove the `Control_R` key from the `modifier_map Control`.

When you want to modify the desktop keyboard shortcuts, you might encounter a problem with assigning the `Mod3` modifier combinations. The walkaround is to modify the registry settings directly, e.g. with commands like that:

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.muffin.keybindings move-to-workspace-down "['<Shift><Mod3>Down']"
gsettings set org.cinnamon.muffin.keybindings move-to-workspace-left "['<Shift><Mod3>Left']"
gsettings set org.cinnamon.muffin.keybindings move-to-workspace-up "['<Shift><Mod3>Up']"
gsettings set org.cinnamon.muffin.keybindings move-to-workspace-right "['<Shift><Mod3>Right']"

gsettings set org.cinnamon.muffin.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down "['<Mod3>Down']"
gsettings set org.cinnamon.muffin.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left "['<Mod3>Left']"
gsettings set org.cinnamon.muffin.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up "['<Mod3>Up']"
gsettings set org.cinnamon.muffin.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right "['<Mod3>Right']"
```

These commands work with Cinnamon 16.